# How can I send an email via C# and get the email address of the sender without letting him send the message from his account

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, gmail

I have a website where the user must send certain info about his car and these information contain also his email address so that I can reply and send him a message.

the messages in this website are being sent and my code is:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   

        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");


            mail.To.Add("myemailaddress");


            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
           SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemailaddress, "mypassword");

            mail.From = new MailAddress(TextBox3.Text);//gets the email address of the sender
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;



            mail.Subject = "subject";
            mail.Body = "body";

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);



            string script = "alert(\"Email was sent!\");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                                  "ServerControlScript", script, true);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Response.Write(ex.ToString());
            string script = "alert(\"Email was not sent!\");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);


        }
```

That's working perfectly but as you can see the message is being sent from my email address and to my email address not from the sender's account.

So I can't reply unless I get the email address sent by the sender which is contained in textbox3.

The problem is that the sender can write his email incorrectly that way I won't be able to reply to his messages. I thought I can let him retype his email address in a second textbox and I would check if both textboxes contain same email address the message will be sent otherwise it won't get sent. but that is not really a good idea; what can I do to get the correct email address of the sender?

I am doing that because as you know Gmail needs authentication and I don't want to ask the sender to put his password.

Comment: You may get better responses if you add proper punctuation and capitalization. And maybe show some code. All I understood is that emails are being sent.

Comment: No, you don't get to send emails from my account.  How do I know you're *only* sending it to yourself, not to everyone on my contact list?  If you need someone's email address, you include it in the form.  Perhaps you send them a validation email ("someone signed up at xyz.com using this email address.  Was it you?") but I don't give *anyone* the ability to send email from my account, and you shouldn't expect other people to, either.

Comment: it won't be me who will send emails from your account you will be sending emails from your account but from my website that's the idea...

Comment: I reread your revised post and have a new solution posted.

Comment: @RoadieRich that's actually incorrect.  You can use an SMTP server to send from any email address you like - as long as the SMTP server will let allow it.

Comment: @sammarcow yes, but only those sent from my account will have correct DKIM and SPF, and the other server certainly won't have access to my contact list.

Answer (score 0):

You can't alter the from address outside your own with GMail SMTP Server for security reasons.  Either own your own mail server and configure appropriately or send all of the relevant information in the body of the email that was sent to you.  You can provide a link in the body that would open a new message for replies to the sender, or you could create a simple webpage that loads all the information into a form, maybe passed through query string to send a reply email which allows for modification.  Either way you need to rethink your strategy.